# How to search multiple websites simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html

I frequently search the same sites with the same parameters when I'm looking for images / resources / inspiration. I think it would be neat if this could be streamlined somehow.

This describes "How to Make a Search Form With Multiple Search Options":
http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/multi-search.html

..And this how to open multiple pages:
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?72649-Getting-a-link-to-open-two-pages&p=1126632#post1126632

I figured that if I just able to hack these two together, I would be able to reach my goal. But unfortunately I can't program at all.

I'd like to have a web page with an input form [ENTRY] and a search button.
Clicking search, it should open multiple links, for example:

"www.flickr com/search/?q=" [ENTRY] "&l=commderiv&ss=0&ct=0&mt=all&w=all&adv=1"
...and three or four others.

Can this be done in html / javascript? Or do you know of something else that makes this possible for me?

best regards
Chester

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a job posting site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't explicitly answer your question, but should help. If you don't know how to code you should research and learn before trying to accomplish your goals. Below is a little example of how to have 5 inputs, enter 5 links and open new windows with google searches of your query...

***HTML***

Make 5 inputs with unique ID's. Add a button that calls JavaScript function on click

```
<input id="link1" />
<input id="link2" />
<input id="link3" />
<input id="link4" />
<input id="link5" />
<button onClick="open();">Search </button>
```

***JavaScript***

Get text of 5 input links and open new windows doing google searches on them

```
function open(){   
    var search1 = document.getElementById('link1').value;
    var search2 = document.getElementById('link2').value;
    var search3 = document.getElementById('link3').value;
    var search4 = document.getElementById('link4').value;
    var search5 = document.getElementById('link5').value;

    // opens new window window.open("http://someWebSite.com");
    // Google searches this format https://www.google.com/#q=yourSearch

    window.open("https://www.google.com/#q=" + search1);
    window.open("https://www.google.com/#q=" + search2);
    window.open("https://www.google.com/#q=" + search3);
    window.open("https://www.google.com/#q=" + search4);
    window.open("https://www.google.com/#q=" + search5);
}
```